# Trying to link the Dropbox File Upload API to a basic HTML form file Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropbox-api

I am trying to use the `Dropbox Javascript Chooser` to allow users to choose files within their dropbox accounts that they can upload on a form on my website.

So far I've gotten the button displaying and I can go into my dropbox and select a file. However what I haven't figured out is how I can link the file I've selected to one of the forms file inputs.

Basically, the functionality I'd be looking to achieve is the same as the standard `type=file` input but the user selects the file from Dropbox instead.

This is my code which is not working for me, I've checked in the Dev console and can't see any errors being rendered.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="xxxxx000111"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            options = {
                // Required. Called when a user selects an item in the Chooser.
                success: function (files) { //Place it in the file upload
                    alert("Here's the file link: " + files[0].link)
                    $('#fileToUpload')[0].files[0] = files[0].link;
                }
            };
            var button = Dropbox.createChooseButton(options);
            document.getElementById("buttonholder").appendChild(button);
        });

    </script>
    <div id="buttonholder"></div>
    <form>
            My File: <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    </form>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I am going wrong ? I've also tried selecting a file and emailing the form contents to myself but this does not work either. I just can't seem to figure out how to integrate the Dropbox API with the HMTL form.

Answer (score 1):

The Chooser gives you back a URL, so you'll want to put that into a field in your form, and then on the server you'll need to extract the URL and download the file contents. (An `<input type="file">` tag does *not* accept a URL but instead needs to be filled in with a file from the local file system.)

Comment: Ok I will look into this @smarx, I might point out that the reason this is proving so difficult is because I do not have access to the file that processes the form submission as its a third party system. That is why I had hoped to be able to somehow incorporate the file into the already existing `<input type="file">` as the system is configured to work with this.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It may be possible to download the file in JavaScript and then upload again via a standard `<input type="file">` tag, but I'm not sure. I'd look into the `File` and `Blob` APIs (and be sure to check their browser support).